# What open source configuration management software with a GUI is available?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, package-management, users

I want to mange multiple ubuntu desktop(10.04,11.04 and 11.10) from server.

Like i want do following list of thing

1) policy management
2) package management
3) Various system Administration thing
4) user management

It should open source solution,easy to manage(Grpahichal)

Eagerly waiting for reply

Please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I have seen is Puppet. Here's their wiki page describing what it can do:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki

Comment: I looking for graphic console in which i can manage.Does puppet has that

Answer (score 0):

Well... you can just enable the remote desktop feature (VNC) on the "client computers".

You can reach this setting by going to:

system **->** preferences **->** remote desktop

Comment: No i want manage more then one Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Thank you for -1... Maybe you should ask more precisely next time. You can manage multiple ubuntu desktop using this. What you might want is to manage multiple ubuntu desktop clients with one click, means making them all equal, but you didnt say that. I do not want to research this anymore, you were too unfriendly, sorry dude

Comment: Sorry i don't mean that